# Strange Radio buttons behavior with mmenu

Tags: jquery, radio-button, mmenu

I attach an image explaining the issue: it is supposed that Item1 and Item 2 are mutually exclusive due to the radio buttons behavior. But they don't behave as such since both kept checked, plus to get it worse, I can't reverse it, ie: if I want to uncheck some item, nothing happens. They kept checked.
I don't know if this is the correct syntax.

This is the meaningful part of the code which is ver simple as you can see in the image, the proper proper libraries and style sheets files are added, otherwise this couldn't to be displayed.
Thanks for your response.

[image]

```
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <span>
                        <a href="/item1/">Item1</a>     
                        <input type="radio" class="Check" />     
                     </span>                         
                </li>
                <li>    
                    <span>
                        <a href="/item2/">Item2</a>
                        <input type="radio" class="Check" />                                                         
                     </span>                         
                </li>
```

I am applying exactly what is described in the documentation: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/addons/toggles.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the url goes to 404.

Comment: thanks for advicing it I am going to edit my post.

Comment: @DinoMyte it was alreadyvedited, the link is working now

Comment: could you post the script code you are working with ?

Comment: @DinoMyte there's no script, since everything is in the .js and .ccs library files. The only constraint for easiness is to name a class in the way I did in the html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is to handle the radio events inside the plugin:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#menu").mmenu({
  }).on( 'click', 'a[href^="/item"]', function() {
    var radio = $(this).closest('li').find(':radio');
    var label = $('label[for="'+ radio.attr('id') +'"]');
    radio.prop('checked', !radio.prop('checked'));
    if (radio.is(':checked')) {
      label.show();
    } else {
      label.hide();
    }
    var par = $(this).closest('ul');
    par.find(':radio').not(radio).prop('checked', false);
    par.find('label.mm-check').not('label[for="'+ radio.attr('id') +'"]').hide();
    return false;
   }
  );

  $("#menu").data( "mmenu").open();
  $("#menu").find('.mm-check').hide();
});
```

```css
.mm-menu {
  background: #099 !important;
}
.mm-navbar {
  border: none;
}
.mm-search {
  padding: 30px 25px 0 25px;
}
.mm-search input {
  background: none !important;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.8 );
  height: 35px;
}
.mm-listview li > a {
  color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.8 );
}
.mm-listview > li > a {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px 10px 15px 40px;
}
.mm-listview > li > a:hover {
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.8 );
  color: #099;
}
.mm-listview .mm-inset {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.mm-listview .mm-inset a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.5.3/core/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.5.3/core/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <span>
                <a href="/item1/">Item1</a>
                <input type="radio" class="Check" />
             </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>
                <a href="/item2/">Item2</a>
                <input type="radio" class="Check" />
             </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi thanks! @gaemaf it seems a good workaround, however as a newbie of JS/CSS3 I need to ask you, how to handle different items names, like A, B instead of Item1 and Item2. Plus, I don't want this solution could interefere with the others submenu items behavior. Is this possible with this solution?. Thanks!

Comment: Second question, is it supposed to handle in that way? because it isn't documented. The check buttons work well without this workaround. I don't know if it because of a bug. Did you experience the same? thanks again!

Comment: If you take a deep look to the plugin you discover exactly the solution to your problem is like this. So no workaround. Of course you may improve the code, in any case I answered to your question, I hope. If it's ok and solve your problem could you accept and upvote?

Comment: Thanks! @gaemaf,  my confussion came because as I understood in the mmenu documentation, it was rather simpler. For instance, if I apply my code but with check buttons instead of radio buttons, they work as expected without needing any line of code. That simple as that. It seems the class tied to the elements it is enough. That wasn't the case with radio buttons. Maybe I misuderstood the documentation.
As for me is answered, I don't have enough credit to evaluate it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The mmenu creator FredE gave me another way to solve it, much simpler. As a newbie of front web development I missed the group name of the radio buttons.
Now, it works like a charm. I left the updated fiddle just in case could be useful for a newbie like me [mmenu and radio buttons without code](https://jsfiddle.net/rossig7/3bgL5afa/)

```
<input type="radio" name="Radios" class="Check" />
```